# Apple Watch is not updating to WatchOS 2 beta with public profile

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, beta-seed-program

I have the profile installed and have done many restarts on my iPhone and my Watch.

Both devices have the public beta profile[image]

iPhone running iOS 9 beta 4 (after upgrading from public beta 1)
Watch running 1.0.1 atm

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no public beta for WatchOS 2.0. Developers can get WatchOS 2.0 by downloading an [additional provisioning profile](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/download/) for the watch.